# Subspaces of a real vector space defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I suspect I'm overthinking this, but I'm reading something that contains the following (paraphrased): "Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space, $x \in V$, and denoted by $V_x$ the smallest subspace of $V$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $x$."  I'm not really sure what the author means by a subspace of $V$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.  I don't think they mean the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of $x$, as they seem to indicate the space $V_x$ being described is a real vector space.  So, what could they be describing?

Comment: I'd undertand this to mean $x\Bbb Q$

Comment: Of course, above when I said "... the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of $V$ ..." I meant $\mathbb{Q}$-span of $x$, which I assume is what you mean, Hagen.

Answer (score 0):

You see $V$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space. Then the author is talking about the $\mathbb Q$-subspace spanned by $x$. Of course, this is just a compicated way of talking about $\mathbb{Q}x$.

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  Here's some more context: $P$ is a free abelian group coming from all values of integrals of a harmonic 1-form $\rho$ on a manifold.  The author defines a torus as $(P \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}) / P \cong H^1(X, \mathbb{R})^*_\rho / \mathrm{im}(H_1(X, \mathbb{Z}))$, and says $H^1(X, \mathbb{R})^*_\rho$ is the smallest $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace of $H^1(X)$ containing $\rho$.  I don't see how this matches up with $P \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}$ since $P \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}$ is a real vector space, but the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of $\rho$ is not.